# Explicitly apply decorator after defineProperty

Tags: javascript, typescript, mobx

I have typescript code with `"experimentalDecorators": true` which allows me to apply decorators.

Also I'm using mobx witch has decorators like `observable`, `computed` and so on.

Some properties in my code are generated dynamically and I want to apply decorators to them too.

In following code

```
class Smth {
  @observable first = 0;
  declare second: number;

  constructor(
    getSecond: () => number,
  ) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "second", { get: getSecond, configurable: true });

    makeObservable(this);
  }
}
```

I want to do something near this call

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "second", { get: getSecond, configurable: true });
```

so that it would behave like

```
@computed get second() { /* ... */ }
```

**How can I apply `computed` decorator after I used `defineProperty`?**

Comment: Not quite understand why you want something like that, but would this work for your case? `makeObservable(this, { second: computed })`

Comment: @Danila, no: `[MobX] makeObservable second arg must be nullish when using decorators. Mixing @decorator syntax with annotations is not supported.` It can work with `makeAutoObservable` but in this case I should get rid of decorators in the class and write configuration object for every nondefault property.